# Access control plane from another ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access the kubectl of the master node that is running on an ec2 instance. I want to do this from another ec2 instance running on a different vpc. What steps should I take to make this possible?

I have the kubeconfig file on my second machine already but on running kubectl, it gives me a connection error,

Edit: Both the vpcs are private and have the similar CIDR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If both of your **EC2** are in diff VPCs you can do the `VPC peering`.
- If you want to expose your master and K8s setup you can directly use the public IP(if exist) of EC2 and `kubectl` will connect to k8s cluster over the internet.

You can also checkout peering multiple VPC with same cidr range if you are looking for that way : [Multiple VPC and Subnet with same CIDR blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301308/multiple-vpc-and-subnet-with-same-cidr-blocks)

Or : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/peering-configurations-partial-access.html#two-vpcs-peered-specific-cidr

Answer (score 1):

- If your eks api server is private, create peering between the
  VPCs and allow your Second EC2 server's private IP
- If your eks api server is public, you can allow your Second EC2 instance's public IP from the aws console, in the eks security or network section

Comment: Hi Phani, both vpcs are private and have similar CIDR and I have not used eks. Would peering still work in this case??